# How to save a browsers bookmarks indivdually to a PC folder?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, brave

I am Currently using Brave browser. I have a lot of bookmarks 
and would like to download them on to a folder on my PC BUT
as individual links.

How can I accomplish this?

I have managed to export all my bookmarks but its saved 
as a single html file. Perhaps there's a way to analyse the file 
and have the links saved out individually?

Comment: You could potentially do this with a Bash or PowerShell script. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am running on windows 10 and OSX. Could you please share how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick PowerShell script to do this for you. You'll need to update `$bookmarks_file` and `$bookmarks_folder` to point to where you need.

This unfortunately only works in Windows and won't help you with your Mac, as that has a different shortcut format and I don't have a Mac to test on.

```powershell
$bookmarks_file = "bookmarks.html"
$bookmarks_folder = "C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\Shortcuts"
$matches = Get-Content $bookmarks_file -Raw | Select-String -Pattern 'HREF="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)<'  -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches }

foreach ($match in $matches) {
    Write-Host $match.Groups[1].Value' '$match.groups[2].Value
    $filename = $match.groups[2].Value
    $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
    $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
    $filename = $filename -replace $re
    $location = "$($bookmarks_folder)\\$($filename).lnk"
    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$location")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $match.Groups[1].Value
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```

### Explanation

- `$matches = Get-Content $bookmarks_file -Raw | Select-String -Pattern 'HREF="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)<'  -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches }`

  This line reads the links and link titles from the `bookmarks.html` file into an array.
- `foreach ($match in $matches)` will look through the array
- `Write-Host $match.Groups[1].Value' '$match.groups[2].Value` writes the URL and title to the console for reference
- `$filename = $match.groups[2].Value` saves the title of the favorite as the filename
- `$invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $filename = $filename -replace $re` replaces any illegal characters in the filename
- `$location = "$($bookmarks_folder)\\$($filename).lnk"` creates the full path, including the directory
- `$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$location")
  $Shortcut.TargetPath = $match.Groups[1].Value
  $Shortcut.Save()` creates the shortcut using the generated file path and the URL

Comment: Man, thank you so much, awfully kind of you.I will try right now and see how it goes